# Error Compiling for board Arduino Nano while using Adafruit GFX

Tags: programming, adafruit, functions, oled, ssd1306

Whys is this happening to me??
I have to meet a deadline please help!!
Here is my code.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>

#define SCREEN_WIDTH 128 // OLED display width, in pixels
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 64 // OLED display height, in pixels

// Declaration for SSD1306 display connected using software SPI (default case):
#define OLED_MOSI   11
#define OLED_CLK   12
#define OLED_DC    9
#define OLED_CS    8
#define OLED_RESET 10
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT,
  OLED_MOSI, OLED_CLK, OLED_DC, OLED_RESET, OLED_CS);
void drawLine(uint16_t x0, uint16_t y0, uint16_t x1, uint16_t y1, uint16_t color);
void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC = generate display voltage from 3.3V internally
  if(!display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC)) {
    Serial.println(F("SSD1306 allocation failed"));
    for(;;); // Don't proceed, loop forever
}


 
  display.display();
  delay(2000); 

  
  display.clearDisplay();

  
  display.drawPixel(10, 10, SSD1306_WHITE);

  
  display.display();
  delay(2000);
  display.invertDisplay(true);
  delay(1000);
  display.invertDisplay(false);
  delay(1000);
  
  
  }
void loop()
{
drawLine(20,60,5,50,256);


  
}
```

The Error

> C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyB6dO1.ltrans0.ltrans.o: In function
> `loop': C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Sunfox\Sunfox\BP_Plus_ECG\February_11\OLED_Testing_w_Adafruit\Test_2\Test_2/Test_2.ino:51: undefined reference to` drawLine(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned
> int, unsigned int, unsigned int)' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1
> exit status exit status 1 Error compiling for board Arduino Nano.

Comment: Kind Sir @MichelKeijzers what does that even mean?

Comment: I will make an answer.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers But I am using Adafruits built in library. I thought they would have done that for me.

Comment: I thought initially that you want to create your own function, but I made an answer to use the library instead of your own function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you defined a forward declaration for `drawLine`, however I assume you want to call the method (function) inside `display`.

So change

```
drawLine(20,60,5,50,256);
```

into

```
display.drawLine(20,60,5,50,256);
```

And you can remove the forward declaration, because this method is already defined in the library.

```
void drawLine(uint16_t x0, uint16_t y0, uint16_t x1, uint16_t y1, uint16_t color);
```

Note, if you call `drawLine` without an instance (which is `display`), then the linker tries to find the `drawLine` function which it cannot find, so you get a linker error (see `ld returned` in your error, together with `undefined reference`).